# Merge request after or before resolving conflicts

Tags: git, gitlab

Im pretty new to gitlab and to merge requests. I have created a new branch, made my changes, and pushed it to remote. I also have another branch on the remote that I want to merge into. Should I create a merge request in gitlab, and there will be an option to compare branches and resolve conflicts? Or should I somehow merge manually first and only then do the merge request?

Comment: If you want to merge , you can first merge master in to your current branch , by using the command git merge [branchName which you want to merge in to your current branch], which will basically sync all the master changes in to that branch ,if there will be conflicts resolve them all and then push the changes and then again merge the master in to your current branch, once master is merged in to your branch then you can raise a merge request for the merging your branch to remote which is master.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab does not allow to merge merge requests when there are conflicts. Thus, you have to merge or rebase the changes from the branch you want to merge to (e.g. `master`) into your branch, resolve conflicts and push the updated branch.

It does not matter, though, if you create the merge request before or after resolving conflicts. If you opened it before and push the merge, the merge request will be updated automatically. As stated above, it is not possible to accept a merge request containing conflicts.